# Voting notification won't go away despite having voted

Tags: support, voting

The notification bar asking to vote for so community moderator re-appears on every page refresh and I have voted already. I couldn't find any submit buttons, but is there some other action I need to perform besides selecting my first, second and third candidates?

Comment: This is probably due to technical reasons: The banner is shown regardless whether you have voted or not, so each user's "vote state" doesn't have to be determined on every request. Just ignore it, like a real-world advertisement that doesn't react to your already having voted

Comment: @Pekka - LOL, I was a bit concerned maybe the vote has not been registered because of browser incompatibility. Other than that I can tolerate a *notification/advertisement* which is as dumb as a real world one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean the system message?

[image: system message]

If so this gets displayed for as long as it's active - either for 48 hours or until a moderator removes it.

If you mean the notification that pops down then if you click the "X" and **refresh the page** then it won't get shown again.

Neither message "knows" whether you have voted or not.

Comment: Yes I mean the second one (notification). And as far as it's not an indication of your vote not having been received its not a big issue. The closing by clicking 'X' only is good for the current session though.

Comment: @Majid - If you refresh the page it should go away permanently. I've only ever seen it the once.

Comment: As at December 2022, there's a letter icon in the popup. Unread messages are marked with closed letter icons, click on these to "open" the letter i.e. read the message, and make the number go away.